# Printing Staircase pattern using only one loop

Tags: c, loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTMXr.jpg)
I thought about printing this shape only using one loop but I didn't make it and I want to know if it's possible and if it's possible what should I do ?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
            printf("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: Hint: you can use `printf("***")`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%*s***\n", i * 3, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Having only allowing one for loop for the task seems like an artificial constraint, but with that in mind, utilizing some string functions would allow you to perform that task.  Following is a snippet of code utilizing just one for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 24

int main()
{
    char gap[MAX];
    char * stair = "***";

    strcpy(gap, "");

    for (int i = 0; i < (MAX / 3) - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%s%s\n", gap, stair);
        strcat(gap, "   ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Following was the sample output at the terminal.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Stairs/bin/Release$ ./Stairs 
***
   ***
      ***
         ***
            ***
               ***
                  ***
```

See if that meets the spirit of your project.